# Kernel Density Estimation - change legend scale to density per m²

Tags: r, probability-density, kernel-density, spatstat

I have calculated a Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) for a species in **R**, i am using the *ants* data set (ant nests) from *spatstat* for simplicity here, and i would like to have a legend scale with the number of ant nest per measurement unit (e.g. m²). If I understood correctly the KDE legend displays the probability density between 0 and 1, how can I translate this probability in "real-world" densities, for example points (ant nests) per m²?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUXt2.png)

Here the example:

```
require("spatstat")
data(ants)
dat <- ants

# estimate bandwith
h_cox <- bw.diggle(dat)

# calculate KDE
kd_cox <- density(dat, h_cox, diggle=TRUE, se=TRUE, eps=diff(dat$window$xrange)/500)

# Plot KDE, contours and points
plot(kd_cox$estimate, main="KDE ants bw.diggle")
contour(kd_cox$estimate, labels="", add=TRUE, col=gray(.5)) 
points(dat)
```

Comment: You are using the function `density.ppp` in the `spatstat` package, which is a method for the generic function `density`.  The help for `density.ppp` says that it calculates a kernel estimate of the **intensity** of the point pattern, expressed in "points per unit area". So, this function is already doing what you want. You just need to ensure that the point pattern data are in metres. The answer by @EgeRubak explains how.

Comment: Note that a probability density is not a value between 0 and 1. *Probabilities* are values between 0 and 1. A probability *density* is a function that must be integrated to obtain probability values. The probability density can be larger than 1. The total area or volume under the probability density graph is equal to 1.

Comment: @AdrianBaddeley: thank you for explaining! I should have read the help page more closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for a clear question with example data.

```r
library(spatstat)
```

Original `ants` data are given in 0.5 feet units:

```r
ants
#> Marked planar point pattern: 97 points
#> Multitype, with levels = Cataglyphis, Messor 
#> window: polygonal boundary
#> enclosing rectangle: [-25, 803] x [-49, 717] units (one unit = 0.5 feet)
```

Thus the code in the original post gives the intensity in number of points
per “square 0.5 feet”, which would be points per “quarter square foot”.
Use `rescale` without arguments to get usual feet:

```r
ants_ft <- rescale(ants)
ants_ft
#> Marked planar point pattern: 97 points
#> Multitype, with levels = Cataglyphis, Messor 
#> window: polygonal boundary
#> enclosing rectangle: [-12.5, 401.5] x [-24.5, 349.5] feet
```

Use `rescale` with conversion factor and name to get metre:

```r
ants_m <- rescale(ants_ft, 3.2808399, "m")
ants_m
#> Marked planar point pattern: 97 points
#> Multitype, with levels = Cataglyphis, Messor 
#> window: polygonal boundary
#> enclosing rectangle: [-3.81, 122.3772] x [-7.4676, 106.5276] m
```

Area of study region and average numer of points per square metre:

```r
area(ants_m)
#> [1] 9962.028
intensity(ants_m)
#> Cataglyphis      Messor 
#> 0.002911054 0.006825920
intensity(unmark(ants_m))
#> [1] 0.009736973
```

Rerunning the original code with `dat <- ants_m` gives you the
estimated intensity in number of points per square metre:

```r
dat <- ants_m
# estimate bandwith
h_cox <- bw.diggle(dat)
#> Warning: Berman-Diggle Cross-Validation criterion was minimised at right-hand
#> end of interval [0, 7.11]; use argument 'hmax' to specify a wider interval for
#> bandwidth 'sigma'
# calculate KDE
kd_cox <- density(dat, h_cox, diggle=TRUE, se=TRUE, eps=diff(dat$window$xrange)/500)
# Plot KDE, contours and points
plot(kd_cox$estimate, main="KDE ants bw.diggle")
contour(kd_cox$estimate, labels="", add=TRUE, col=gray(.5)) 
points(dat)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Question is solved.

Comment: Is there an intuitive way to counter-check, whether reasonable densities have been estimated?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate the mean intensity (`mean(kd_cox$estimate)`) which should be close to npoints / area or the integral (`integral(kd_cox$estimate)`) which should be close to the total number of points.